# how can css visible overflow content have a non-transparent background so content underneath is hidden?

Tags: css, overflow, transparency

how can css visible overflow content have a non-transparent background so content underneath is hidden?

```
<div class="coverer-container">
    <div class="coverer">
        <p>I want this to have an opaque background.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="coveree">
    <p>So you can not see this text.</p>
</div>

.coverer-container{
    position:relative;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    overflow:visible;
}

.coverer{
    position:absolute;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}
```

[here is my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/JUndB/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.coverer p {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Can't you do this?

Comment: HA! yes, what a numtpy I am. I thought it was too simple to even try :S, thanks!

Comment: He said non-transparent background, not white.
Edit: oh, well then. Just saw that he added a comment.

Comment: @RaulGogo non-transparent = any color. They can just change it how they need.

Comment: true, all I wanted was for the overflown content to cover up what was beneath it, I can't believe I didn't try explicitly setting the background color, I thought it would have been set to that automatically so I din't try it

Comment: @0xor1 the body and inputs are pretty much the only elements with a background color by default.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 does it not inherit from its parent?

Comment: Not unless you set `background: inherit;`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to achieve this. Each has effect with browsers, example, IE and other browsers may not respond well to opacity command.

Aside from that, it is not logical and some search engines can penalty flag you - of course depending on the amount you do it etc.

Demo **[ [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JUndB/8/) ]**

```
.coverer{
position:absolute;
height:300px;
width:300px;
display:block;
background:#fff;
}
.coveree{}
```

You can even add opacity commands but this will still see your text below and also z-index and also display:hidden and visibility usage...

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index: **http://jsfiddle.net/HZL8c/**

HTML

```
<div class="coverer">
    <p>I want this to have an opaque background.</p>
</div>
<div class="coveree">
    <p>So you can not see this text.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.coverer{
    border: 1px solid green;
    position:absolute;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #fff;
}

.coveree{
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```